# What is the best/complete/correct why of handling infinite loops? (JAVA)

Tags: java, testing, exception, infinite-loop

In the code below, the infinite loop occurs at the for loop. Because if mtu = 8. Then (i = i + (mtu - 8)) will always be 0 because the value of i never changes.

I inserted an if statement that says, if "(i = i + (mtu - 8))" does equal 0, then execute some code, else print an error message. I am aware that this if statement has introduced a new bug if "mtu = 10".

What is the best/complete/correct why of breaking infinite loops? Should I be using an if statement? Or is there another way to handle this?

```
    private static List<String> splitFrame(String message) {
    List<String> slicedMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    int len = message.length();
    if (message.length() > mtu - 8) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += (mtu - 8)) { // Infinite loop occurs here. Because if mtu = 8. Then (i = i + (mtu - 8)) will always be 0.
            if (!((i += (mtu - 8)) == 0)) { // I try to stop the infinite loop by this if statement. If the sum does not equal 0, then exectute some code.
                try {
                    slicedMessage.add(message.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + (mtu - 8))));
                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("String Index Out Of Bounds --> Method splitFrame"); // TODO Replace sout with terminal.printDiag from the "MessageSender" class.
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("MTU can not be set to 8"); // TODO Replace sout with terminal.printDiag from the "MessageSender" class.
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(createFrame(message));
    }
    return slicedMessage;
}
```

Comment: Please **read** about the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll look into it. @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `mtu` is not changing, there is no need to enter the loop if mtu = 8.

```
private static List<String> splitFrame(String message) {
    List<String> slicedMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    int len = message.length();
    int diff = mtu - 8;
    if (diff != 0 && len > diff) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += diff) {
            try {
                slicedMessage.add(message.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + (diff))));
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("String Index Out Of Bounds --> Method splitFrame"); // TODO Replace sout with terminal.printDiag from the "MessageSender" class.
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(createFrame(message));
    }
    return slicedMessage;
}
```